# how to insert data into a dynamically created row in a table (html) from database using php and mysqli

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli

i have a database filled with records. im trying to fetch that data and show it in a table which is dynamically created when search a particular name.

my html code is

```
<form class="formm" method="POST" action="">  

          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <input  type="text" name="name" id="nameee" placeholder="Name"  />
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" name="vNum" id="vNum" placeholder="Voucher Number" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' maxlength="7" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" name="cnic" id="cnic" placeholder="CNIC Number - (4444455555556)" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' maxlength="13" />
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="button" name="search" id="search" onclick="myFunction()">
          </div>
</form>


<div class="row" id="tableDiv">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <table id="Resulttable" class="table table-hover table-mc-light-blue">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Voucher Number</th>
              <th>Cnic Number</th>
              <th>Phone Number</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>  
          <tbody>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>      
</div>
```

my php code is

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dany";
$rowc_name;
$rowc_id;
$rowc_cnic;
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT c_name, c_cnic, c_id FROM customer";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $rowc_name = $row["c_name"];
  $rowc_id =  $row["c_id"];
  $rowc_cnic = $row["c_cnic"];
  echo "<br> id: ". $row["c_id"]. " - Name: ". $row["c_name"]. " " . $row["c_cnic"] . "<br>";


    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

this code fetches the data and displays it as is on the page on the upper left corner.
the problem is:
im unable to load it on the table cells.

i cannot write a javascript function which on clicking the "search button on my form" inserts this information on the table.

im guessing a javascript function, which triggers when the search button is clicked, fetches an entry from the database according to the value entered in the textbox, and displays it on the table.

keep in mind that there can be multiple entries in the database with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You must use ajax to do this. It's very easy if you use jQuery to do this. For example a simple code you can run:

```
$("button").click(function(){
   $.ajax({url: "yourphpcode.php", success: function(result){
     // You can do your work with result
  }});
});
```

You can see more example from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use while loop inside table to show data inside your table like this :

```
<table>
<thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
 <th>id</th>
 <th>password</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
 //use your while loop here //
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($varname){
  //close your php tag because table is a html element//
?>
    <td>Name</td>
 <td>id</td>
 <td>password</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
//start your php and end while loop end bracket//
<?php } ?>
```

This code will show all your database data in a table in proper format.     If you have another PHP page, include that PHP to current table page.